# solution for finding how may times a record visited(no of occurances) with millions of record without using high ram

Tags: python, count

i am running through 100 million records and count number of occurances(no of repeated records) using dictionary

```
import os
import re
import glob

map_url = dict()

for f1 in glob.glob('*.urls'):
    urls = open(f1,'r')
    for url in urls:
        url = re.sub(r'\n','',url)
        #print url
        if url in map_url:
            count = map_url[url]
            count = count + 1
            map_url[url] = count
            #print url,count
        else:
            map_url[url] = 1
            #print url,1

print map_url
```

Lets say if i store millions of record in dictionary i will run out of physical memory right

Do we have any solution to run this with less space(limiting bytes) without using any database ????

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database? If you have too much data to store in memory, that's probably the easiest way to store it on the disk instead.

Comment: I just want to know is there any other solution using algorithms

Comment: What do you mean *"using algorithms"*?

Comment: Try using NumPy arrays instead of dictionaries, they are much more memory efficient. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: Current approach uses `O(n)` time and `O(n)` memory space, which most would consider most optimal. In your case you don't want to use `O(n)` memory space, which will mean increase in running time. You could scan database for every element to determine if it's duplicate. This is `O(n^2)` time but `O(1)` memory.